# Switch between public view and draft view

Tags: support, documentation

I had saved a draft to a documentation topic, then someone proposed a change to the same topic. This proposed changed got accepted. Now when I click on the "All topics" tab, and then select the topic in question, I get this "Edit topic view" where the screen is split in two with the topic editor in the bottom half of the screen. Here I am "forced" to continue editing my saved draft. How can I get the public view of the topic, in order to see how the accepted change (provided by the other user) looks for other users?

Comment: I think you can got to topic history, find the last change and see the diff. However, easy switching between public and draft view is still something I'm totally interested in. Also I want to see **diff between public and draft** versions, couldn't find how to do it. Considering I always check a diff before committing to a repository, I feel lost.

Comment: @Squidward Yes completely agree. For example, if I did some edits to one example one day and saved to draft, then some days later I modify another example within the same topic (and the same draft). Now I would like to publish the draft. But I forgot the details of the first edit. How to provide a decent commit message when you cannot review the diffs since last commit? The only solution is to provide a dummy ( a guess ) commit message and submit for review, then retract the edit immediately after you checked the diff in the submitted change (here the diff is available, as green colored text).

Comment: .. (contd.) ..Then resubmit the edit with correct commit message..